# How to not retrieve duplicate row due to stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I've been using my stored procedure to retrieve events filter by : a date start, a date end, a shopId, a sellerId and customerId.

First of all, here the principal structure of my database which causes me the problem :

Ticket:

| Id | Reference | .. | .. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15222 | BOOKING56654 | .. | .. |

Seller :

| Id | Name | .. | .. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 41 | Caty | .. | .. |
| 47 | Stephane | .. | .. |

TicketSeller :

| SellerId | TicketId |
| --- | --- |
| 47 | 15222 |
| 41 | 15222 |

It works good, when I save my ticket with multiple seller, it saves in the many to many relation TicketSeller, two rows. That's normal.

But when I execute my stored procedure, instead of retrieving only a row, it retrieves me two rows because of this relation many to many in TicketSeller.
The problem might be when I join the tables but I didn't success of fix it.

Here the code in my stored procedure when I do the join between those tables :

```
(...)
    FROM Ticket t 
    JOIN TicketSeller ts ON ts.TicketId = t.Id
    JOIN Seller e ON e.Id = ts.SellerId
    JOIN Customer c ON c.Id = t.CustomerId
    JOIN TicketProduct tp ON tp.TicketId = t.Id
    JOIN Product p ON p.Id = tp.ProductId
    LEFT JOIN Category ca ON ca.Id = p.CategoryId
    WHERE t.LicenseId = @licenseId AND t.[State] > 0 AND t.Type = 2 AND
    t.BookingAt >= @dateStart AND t.BookingEnd <= @dateEnd AND 
    ((@shopId is not null AND t.ShopId = @shopId) OR (@shopId = 0 AND t.ShopId > 0)) AND
    ((@sellerId > 0 AND t.SellerId = @sellerId) OR (@sellerId = 0 AND t.SellerId > 0)) AND
    ((@customerId > 0 AND t.CustomerId = @customerId) OR (@customerId = 0 AND t.CustomerId > 0))
```

Comment: ideally, you should not receive duplicate data, as you are having condition: `((@sellerId > 0 AND t.SellerId = @sellerId) OR (@sellerId = 0 AND t.SellerId > 0)) AND` . If you pass @sellerId = 47, are you getting two rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code example the *Ticket* table is aliased as 't' and the *TicketSeller* is aliased as 'ts'

```
FROM Ticket t 
    JOIN TicketSeller ts ON ts.TicketId = t.Id
```

and in your description of your tables, the *SellerId* is in the *TicketSeller* table

```
 ((@sellerId > 0 AND t.SellerId = @sellerId) OR (@sellerId = 0 AND t.SellerId > 0))
```

You are using `t.SellerId` and not `ts.SellerId`

If this is the correct code (and not just a spelling mistake), then I think this is why you have double records.